# How to detect if an array contains any value that is a specific length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as follows:

```
var array = ['Bob','F', 'Nichols'];
```

I want to detect whether this array contains any values that are a single character long. In other words, I want to know whether there are any initials in this person's name.

```
var array = ['Bob','F', 'Nichols']; //true
var array = ['B','Freddy', 'Nichols']; //true
var array = ['Bob','Freddy', 'N']; //true
var array = ['B','F', 'N']; //true
var array = ['B','F', 'N']; //true
var array = ['Bob','Freddy', 'Nichols']; //false

if (anyInitials(array)) {
    console.log("there are initials");
} else {
    console.log("there are no initials");
}

function anyInitials(a) {
    var arrayLength = a.length;
    var initial = 'no';
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            if (a[i].length == 1){
                initial = 'yes';
            }
        }
    return initial;
}
```

Comment: `//no idea` The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `some`

```js
let array = ['Bob','F', 'Nichols'];
console.log(array.some(({length}) => length === 1));
```

```
let anyInitials = a => a.some(({length}) => length === 1) ? "yes" : "no";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop like below. This loops through the array, and sets `isInitial` to true if the length is 1.

```js
var array = ['Bob', 'F', 'Nichols'];

function anyInitials(a) {
  var isInitial = false;
  a.forEach(e => {
    if (e.length == 1) {
      isInitial =  true;
    }
  });
  
  return isInitial;
}

console.log(anyInitials(array));
```

You can also use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like below. This will return true if any element in the array has a length of 1.

```js
var array = ['Bob', 'F', 'Nichols'];

function anyInitials(a) {
  return array.some(e => e.length == 1); 
}

console.log(anyInitials(array));
```